# ByteBuffer vs byte[] vs ArrayList

Tags: java

Где лучше хранить 50 Мб из бинарного файла после того как их выкачал InputStream? Лучше = быстрее.

Comment: а потому что ты с ними делать будешь?

Comment: Скормлю видеокарте через VBO

Comment: Тогда вариант 1.

Comment: Тут, пожалуй, и язык знать не надо, просто уметь логически думать.  

- ByteBuffer  - буфер для байтов.
- ArrayList - список на основе массива.

Кажется, ответ очевиден? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ByteBuffer - обёртка над byte[], так что, если вопрос в скорости, надо быть проще - использовать byte[]. Особенно если в качестве потока данных выступает ByteArrayInputStream и не надо ничего преобразовывать.